# ExtJS Maximum call stack size exceeded when reordering tree

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

I'm reordering the hierarchy of a tree with drag and drop. After moving multiple nodes I get the error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. The error appears in `NodeInterface.js`.  The `updateInfo` function crashes in the following line

`for (i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
     children[i].updateInfo(commit, childInfo);
}`

What could cause this problem?

The following code shows how I implemnted the drag and drop and reordering in ExtJS 6.5.2. Maybe you can find what's causing the problem.

**Plugin**

```
Ext.define('test.component.plugin.TreeDragger', {
extend: 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
alias: 'plugin.treedrag',

mixins: ['Ext.mixin.Observable'],

constructor: function (config) {
    this.mixins.observable.constructor.call(this, config);
},

init: function (component) {
    var me = this;

    this.source = new Ext.drag.Source({
        element: component.element,
        handle: '.x-gridrow',
        constrain: {
            element: true,
            vertical: true
        },
        describe: function (info) {
            var row = Ext.Component.from(info.eventTarget, component);
            info.row = row;
            info.record = row.getRecord();
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'placeholder',
            getElement: function (info) {
                console.log('proxy: getElement');                    

                var el = Ext.getBody().createChild({
                    style: 'padding: 10px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid gray; color: red;',
                });
                el.show().update(info.record.get('description'));
                return el;
            }
        },
        // autoDestroy: false,
        listeners: {
            scope: me,
            beforedragstart: me.makeRelayer('beforedragstart'),
            dragstart: me.makeRelayer('dragstart'),
            dragmove: me.makeRelayer('dragmove'),
            dragend: me.makeRelayer('dragend')
        }
    });
},

disable: function () {
    this.source.disable();
},

enable: function () {
    this.source.enable();
},

doDestroy: function () {
    Ext.destroy(this.source);
    this.callParent();
},

makeRelayer: function (name) {
    var me = this;
    return function (source, info) {
        return me.fireEvent(name, me, info);
    };
}
});
```

**Tree**

```
xtype: 'tree',
    hideHeaders: true,

    plugins: {
        treedrag: {
            type: 'treedrag',
            listeners: {
                beforedragstart: function (plugin, info) {
                    console.log('listeners: beforedragstart');
                }
            }
        }
    },
    columns: [{
            xtype: 'treecolumn',
            flex: 1,
        }
    ]
```

**Controller**

```
afterLoadApportionmentObjectsForTree: function (succes) {
    if (succes) {

        tree = this.getView().down('tree');
        if (tree) {
            tree.expandAll();
            tree.updateHideHeaders(tree.getHideHeaders());
            var store = tree.getStore();
            store.remoteFilter = false;
            store.filterer = 'bottomup';

            this.createDropTargets();
        }
    }
},

createDropTargets: function () {
    var me = this,
        rows = tree.innerItems;
    Ext.each(rows, function (el) {
        var target = new Ext.drag.Target({
            element: el.element,
            listeners: {
                scope: me,
                drop: me.onDrop
            }
        });
    });
},

onDrop: function (target, info, eOpts) {
    var source = info.record,
        row = Ext.Component.from(target.getElement(), tree),
        destination = row.getRecord(),
        parentNode = source.parentNode;

    destination.appendChild(source);
    destination.expand();

    if (!parentNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        parentNode.set('leaf', true);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

It seems that `updateInfo` is called recursive, but I can't figure out why or how I could prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find the mistake by myself. It was possible to drag nodes on their own children which relates to an recursive adding and removing of the same nodes over and over again. To prevent the user from doing this, I added an listener for the `beforeDrop` event to my `Ext.drag.Target`. There it returns `false`, if the target node is the same as the source node and it returns `false` if the target node is a child node of the source node.

```
 onBeforeDrop: function (target, info, eOpts) {
    var source = info.record,
        row = Ext.Component.from(target.getElement(), tree),
        destination = row.getRecord();

    if (source == destination) {
        return false;
    }
    if (source.findChild('number', destination.get('number'), true) != null) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I also used the `beforedragstart` event to prevent moving the root node.

Maybe this is helpful for someone else.